# boto3 load custom models

Tags: api, session, model, boto3

For example:

```py
session = boto3.Session()
client = session.client('custom-service')
```

I know that I can create a json with API definitions under ~/.aws/models and botocore will load it from there. The problem is that I need to get it done on the AWS Lambda function, which looks like impossible to do so.

Looking for a way to tell boto3 where are the custom json api definitions so it could load from the defined path.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have only a partial answer. There's a bit of documentation about `botocore`'s [`loader` module](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/loaders.html), which is what reads the model files. In a disscusion about loading models from ZIP archives, [a monkey patch was offered up](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/749#issuecomment-237713460) which extracts the ZIP to a temporary filesystem location and then extends the loader search path to that location. It doesn't seem like you can load model data directly from memory based on the API, but Lambda does give you some scratch space in `/tmp`.

Here's the important bits:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session()
session._loader.search_paths.extend(["/tmp/boto"])
client = session.client("custom-service")
```

The directory structure of `/tmp/boto` needs to follow the resource loader documentation. The main model file needs to be at `/tmp/boto/custom-service/yyyy-mm-dd/service-2.json`.

---

The issue also mentions that alternative loaders can be swapped in using `Session.register_component` so if you wanted to write a scrappy loader which returned a model straight from memory you could try that too. I don't have any info about how to go about doing that.

Comment: thanks, that works great. Key think that wasnt obvious to me is that the json file must really be named service-2.json :)

Answer (score 3):

Just adding more details:

```py
import boto3
import zipfile
import os
    
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('your-bucket','model.zip','/tmp/model.zip')
    
os.chdir('/tmp')
with zipfile.ZipFile('model.zip', 'r') as archive:
    archive.extractall()
        
session = boto3.Session()
session._loader.search_paths.extend(["/tmp/boto"])
client = session.client("custom-service")
```

model.zip is just a compressed file that contains:

```
Archive:  model.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  11-04-2020 16:44   boto/
        0  11-04-2020 16:44   boto/custom-service/
        0  11-04-2020 16:44   boto/custom-service/2018-04-23/
    21440  11-04-2020 16:44   boto/custom-service/2018-04-23/service-2.json
```

Just remember to have the proper lambda role to access S3 and your custom-service.

Answer (score 3):

boto3 also allows setting the `AWS_DATA_PATH` environment variable which can point to a directory path of your choice.

[[boto3 Docs]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#using-environment-variables)

Everything zipped with your lambda function is put under `/opt/`.

Let's assume all your custom models live under a `models/` folder. When this folder is mounted to the lambda environment, it'll live under `/opt/models/`.

Simply specify `AWS_DATA_PATH=/opt/models/` in the Lambda configuration and boto3 will pick up models in that directory.

This is better than fetching models from S3 during runtime, unpacking, and then modifying session parameters.